# C question about passing a string as a function agrument

Tags: c

I would like to pass a string to function like this..

```
 long_var = get_value("long_value");
 short_var = get_value("short_value");
```

Inside the function, I did this..

```
double get_value(char *get_type){

   if  (*get_type == "short_value")
   {
        //calculate and return
    }
   else if  (*get_type == "long_value")
   {
         //calculate and return
    }  
}
```

However, i have an error
Error: main.c(334): function argument #1 of type 'flash unsigned char [11]' is incompatible with required parameter of type 'unsigned char *'

I thought that a string was just an array of char and I can call it..

Also, is there a better way to do this..

Thanks..

Comment: and line 314 is which one? I can tell you that you need to use strcmp.

Comment: what is flash unsigned char[11]?

Comment: The compiler complains when I call the function with a string argument

Comment: it shouldn't complain. Is this your actual code?it shouldn't complain. Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 6):

You are going to need to include `<string.h>` and change your code to say

```
 if (!strcmp(get_type, "short_value"))
```

The way things are now, you are comparing a character (`*get_type`) with a pointer to a character (`"short_value"`).

Comment: Your code is wrong. Think about it: what does `strcmp()` return if two strings are equal?

Comment: I am in micro controller platform and I would like to avoid using `string.h`

Comment: @Programming Enthusiast - Then don't use strings. Use an `enum` (or `#define`s) to have names that you can test with `==` (and `switch` on).

Comment: don't use strings at all then!

Answer (score 4):

You should pass constant strings as "const char*" or even "const char * const".
Also, c-strings are plain arrays and using == operation on them will just compare pointers, not strings. You should use strcmp function for comparison.

Comment: `const * char *` is too many pointers, but `const char *` is the correct way to pass a (non-mutable) string.

Comment: Oh, sorry, temporary brain dis-function, of course I have meant const * char const

Comment: Sure you didn't now mean `const char * const`?

Comment: Hm, 3:54 AM.
Convinced. These are not the droids I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

String literals are of type `const char[]`, which decays to `const char *` in the function call, so you should make the signature of your function `double get_value(const char *)`.

Second, when you dereference `*get_type`, you only get *one char*, not the entire string! And then you're trying to compare that char to an array (which again decays to a pointer) -- that doesn't work. What you need is `strcmp` (or a variant version thereof):

```
if (!strcmp(get_type, "short_value")) { ... }`
```

If you prefer, you can say `strncmp(get_type, "short_value", 12)` and only compare the initial 12 characters, which is the length of "short_value" including its terminating null byte - not strictly necessary, but it's good to be aware of one's string lengths when using string manipulation functions.

Comment: ==0 would be a better test surely

Comment: and strncmp would be no safer at alland strncmp would be no safer at all

Comment: It wouldn't in this situation, but in the spirit of getting people never to use `strcmp`, it'd be bad to encourage it here.

Comment: @David - Personally I prefer `!strcmp` to `strcmp == 0`, but it depends on your coding standards I suppose. I don't usually test if strings are greater or less than other strings, only if they're equal to other strings, so I never get messed up by the asymmetry of `!strcmp` to other comparisons. (Or to be really evil, you could do `#define STRCMP(x, op, y) (strcmp((x), (y)) op 0)` and allow people to do `if(STRCMP("this", ==, "that"))`)

Comment: @Kerrek SB - "Getting people never to use `strcmp`" is not something I'm in the spirit for. Dogmatically avoiding a function that's only sometimes unsafe for a function that's only slightly safer isn't a good way to program. Ensuring that your code is safe (e.g. by testing) in the first place is a far better practice.

Comment: What about this way, it works but its less clear..
`
#define long_value 1
#define short_value 2

double get_value(unsigned int);

double get_value(unsigned int get_type){

   if  (get_type == short_value )
   {
        //calculate and return
    }
   else if  (get_type == long_value)
   {
         //calculate and return
    }  
}`

Comment: @Chris: OK, fine, `strcmp` is OK, and you can still shoot yourself in the toe with `strncmp`. Just make sure that you have null-terminated strings... (I'll edit this to rephrase.)

Comment: @Programming Enthusiast: You're essentially describing an `enum`, which would be a much better solution than string comparison in any case.

Comment: @programming it works, it's more efficient, and it is in fact clearer. Strings are terrible when used as enums.

Comment: the 12 in the call to strncmp is trouble in the making. One day you change the string making it longer but forget to change the 12.

Comment: @David: yeah, OK, those should be constants anyway and then you'd have `sizeof`... but this is much better done with enums, as we just said, so I won't belabour this.

Comment: Not to belabor this either, which is a better way to.. I tried both and  I think  using an enum would like a bit more memory than using the define, although its clearer..

Comment: @Programming: First you want to compare strings and now you worry about the efficiency of an enum? :-) But seriously, both the `#define` and the enum are integral values that probably end up occupying the same minimal space (one register), so I'd prefer the semantic nature of enums over a dumb macro any day.

Comment: ok.. great comment, i always feel uncomfortable when defining macro's as well